# What framework to use for my web app?

Tags: webapps

I am currently putting together a quick web app for Ubuntu touch. Everything is sorted but I can't figure out which framework to select in the manifest.json.

I have tried a few but I get: 'ubuntu-sdk-14.10-html' is not a supported framework

According to this it should work:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t_JGpg4r8BLluzfzmqa-gAbcKUjKUOufSCTSdPpFc5g/edit#gid=0

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.1 with all the updates.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you use "devel" as image base, or an utopic baseline; unfortunately, the final 14.10 frameworks are missing from this bases, but 14.09 rtm images, or vivid images have them.

We should update our devel alias and/or update our utopic base though.